# fixing span width

Tags: css

I have this table1 inside of a span tag (span is inside of td tag)

the problem is that the row data of the Table1 is appearing outside of `td` ...the data should appear within the boundaries of `td` tag..right ? coz the span is contained within the td tag...how do I make sure that the width of span remains fixed..like it shouldn't display stuff outside of `td` tag which is its container

Firebug shows table1's width as 100%

**[Edit]**

ok I added `display:block;` in span tag first..didnt work...when I added the same in Table tag the columns of the Table shrank..ie spaces between col.s shrank and row data isn't anymore displaying outside of td's area

Now what I wanna ask is that if I set `Table{display:block;}` in the css file..how would it affect other tables ??I don't want other tables to get screwed up...Just want this one fixed..Also, the table is being created on runtime using Telerik's RadEditor so will display:block fix table's width and not let its rows' data flow outside td area??

Comment: You have a table within a span or a span within a td?

Comment: Tables are block elements, there's no need to set this. Please post your code so we can take a better look, or a live example. You can use jsfiddle.net to set up a temporary example of you cannot allow access to your live site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<span>`s are inline elements, like `<a>` and `<img>`, therefore they cannot accept rules like width:, height: and others.

To allow the `<span>` to accept these rules, add `display: block;` to the Span's CSS.

This will allow it to accept the width rule and fill up your TD.

That or just change your `<span>` to a `<div>`.

If that doesn't work, post your code and we'll take a closer look :)

Answer (score 3):

A span is an inline element and so cannot have an explicit width set. What is in the span? If it's a continuous string then there is no way for the browser to know where to cut the string and make it wrap. If you don't want to see the excess content then you can set overflow:hidden on the  element but that's not always a good idea. Perhaps post the code you are working with and we can provide more specific help.